# I get some Problem when i execute update query in java

Tags: java, sql-server

I have some problem when I execute an update query , The index 1 is out of range.

```
public void updateAnswer(String Answer, String correct, String Id_Question, int id) throws SQLException, Exception {
    try {
            //UPDATE Answer SET Answer = ':: A. 10 ::B.15 ::C.20 ::D.5' ,Correct_Answer= 'B' WHERE Id = 151;

        conn = DataConnection.getConnectionToSQLSever();
        sqlStr = "UPDATE Answer SET Answer = '?', Correct_Answer = '?' WHERE Id =?;";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        pst.setString(1, Answer);
        pst.setString(2, correct);
        pst.setInt(3, id);
        System.out.println(pst.toString());
        pst.executeUpdate();
        findAnswerId(Id_Question).setAnswer(Answer);
        findAnswerId(Id_Question).setCorrect(correct);

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: You may receive that error message when you use an escaped single quotation mark to set a parameter value for a prepared statement in the SQL Server 2005 JDBC Driver.

Comment: Please read [mcve] and enhance your question accordingly. Include the relevant parts of the stack trace for example.

Comment: Dont use single quotes around question mark.

Comment: which line is giving you the exception?  you should be able to debug and step through the code.

Comment: ya i try to use RIch text box and load it to my website but it doesn't work ! Pls some one show me how to use its !!

Answer (score 1):

Your first two question marks are treated as literals, in effect, you only have one parameter, taht's why you're receiving index out of range. 
Remove the single quotes, the ? alone is enough to expect a string parameter

Answer (score 0):

try this code.

```
        conn = DataConnection.getConnectionToSQLSever();
        sqlStr = "UPDATE Answer SET Answer = ?, Correct_Answer = ? WHERE Id = '" + id + "'";

        pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStr);
        pst.setString(1, Answer);
        pst.setString(2, correct);
        pst.setInt(3, id);
        pst.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Instead of `WHERE Id = '" + id + "'";`, the code should be `WHERE Id = ?`.

Comment: Thank you, The problem has been solved. !!